# Where are the network manager configuration files?

Tags: configuration, network-manager

I have a network that my machine tries to connect to automatically...
   it's a network that requires LEAP authentication so I have a username stored with the network.
However, my username has changed but the network does not show up in the list when I do "edit connections".

Where is the configuration file so that I can edit it by hand?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager#Editing_Network_Settings_in_GConf

That link seems pretty up to date.  Basically, can be stored in two places.  On my oneiric box, I see most everything under /etc/NetworkManager.